# ASP.Net MVC3 app downloading files to client from another network server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, download

We currently use the code below to download files from a network server to the client in an old ASP.net page.

We have re-written the app in MVC3 and would like to upgrade this functionality. I have seen several posts that claim you can access the file from the network share by writing the following lines in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="" password="" />
```

However, we are currently using Forms authentication mode to logon to the site. Would that interfere with the login functionality?

Here's our download code.

```
Partial Class DownloadFile2
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

   Private BufferSize As Integer = 32 * 1024

   Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      Dim path As String = Request.Params("File")
      path = "\\speedy\wanfiles\" + path.Substring(3)
      Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(path)
      Dim Buffer(BufferSize) As Byte
      Dim SizeWritten, fileindex As Integer
      Response.Clear()

      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name)
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString)

      Response.ContentType = "application/octet-type"
      Response.Flush()

      fileindex = 0
      Do
         // not sure about this GM.AlasData code below
         SizeWritten = GM.AlasData.ReadFileBlock(file.FullName, Buffer, fileindex, BufferSize) 
         Response.OutputStream.Write(Buffer, 0, SizeWritten)
         Response.Flush()
         If SizeWritten < BufferSize Then
            Exit Do
         Else
            fileindex = fileindex + SizeWritten
         End If
      Loop

      Response.End()


   End Sub

End Class
```

I found this code to do downloads using MVC3 but cannot access the file because it is considered a local file.

```
public FileResult Download(string FilePath)
{
    if (FilePath != null)
    {
        string path = FilePath;
        string contentType;
        // files are stored on network server named speedy
        path = string.Concat(@"\\speedy\files\", HttpUtility.UrlDecode(path));
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(file.Extension.ToLower());
        if (rk != null && rk.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
        {
            contentType = rk.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            contentType = "application/octet-type";
        }

        //Parameters to file are
        //1. The File Path on the File Server
        //2. The content type MIME type
        //3. The parameter for the file save by the browser
        return File(file.FullName, contentType, file.Name);

    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What needs to be done to fix this where we can perform this functionality?

Comment: "cannot access the file because it is considered a local file" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: The question explains that I'm trying to access a file on a network server different from my web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4051/Windows-Impersonation-using-C

Comment: I'll have to check that one out.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the Authentication mode = windows line since you are using forms authentication. Use the impersonation and make sure the account has read access to the network location you are trying to access. that should work.

Comment: Do you not have to have authentication mode = Windows if you want to impersonate user? The bounty asks for working example.

Comment: no. authentication mode="Windows", is just to switch to the windows authentication mode. since you are using forms authentication, you would switch to authentication mode="Forms". These are the possible values you can have in the authentication mode: <system.web>
   <!-- mode=[Windows|Forms|Passport|None] -->
   <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>. Impersonation just means that you are running your application under the impersonated user. So if your impersonated user has access to network, then your application will be able to download the file from the network.

Comment: It is ALREADY in Forms mode. Where is working example showing how to impersonate the user to do this?